# Domain of a function is all the elements of the first set?

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics, relations

I am reading about functions in the textbook "Discrete Mathematical Structures" by Kolman et.al. They have given in an example that 
\begin{equation}
A=\{1,2,3\} \quad\text{and}\quad B=\{x,y,z\}
\end{equation}

Then $R=\{(1,x),(2,x)\}$ is a function.

But a google search revealed that this is not a function since 3 is not involved.

Whether the book is wrong or I got something wrong

Comment: I think definitions can be different. Some call $R$ in your example a *partial function*, as opposed to a *total function*, which is commonly called just *function*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At least in the third edition of Kolman et al., *function* is defined as follows:

> Let $A$ and $B$ be nonempty sets. A **function** $f$ from $A$ to $B$, which is denoted $f:A\to B$, is a relation from $A$ to $B$ such that for all $a\in\operatorname{Dom}(f)$, $f(a)$ contains just one element of $B$. Naturally, if $a$ is not in $\operatorname{Dom}(f)$, then $f(a)=\varnothing$. If $f(a)=\{b\}$, it is traditional to identify the set $\{b\}$ with the element $b$ and write $f(a)=b$.

This obviously depends on some prior definitions and conventions relating to relations. They define a **relation** $R$ **from** $A$ **to** $B$ in the usual way, as a subset of $A\times B$, and immediately introduce the notation $a\,R\,b$. The **domain** of $R$ is then defined (in words) to be $$\operatorname{Dom}(R)=\left\{a\in A:\exists b\in B\big(a\,R\,b\big)\right\}\;,$$ and examples make it clear that $\operatorname{Dom}(R)$ need not be all of $A$. Finally, for $a\in A$ they define $R(a)=\{b\in B:a\,R\,b\}$.

If $A=\{1,2,3\}$, $B=\{x,y,z\}$, and $R=\{\langle 1,x\rangle,\langle 2,x\rangle\}$, then certainly $R\subseteq A\times B$, so $R$ is a relation from $A$ to $B$. $\operatorname{Dom}(R)=\{1,2\}$, $R(1)=\{x\}$, and $R(2)=\{x\}$, so it’s true that $f(a)$ contains just one element of $B$ for each $a\in\operatorname{Dom}(R)$. Thus, $R$ does indeed satisfy their definition of *function from* $A$ *to* $B$.

However, what they call a function from $A$ to $B$ is more commonly called a *partial function* from $A$ to $B$, i.e., a function from a subset of $A$ to $B$. Many people reserve the term *function from* $A$ *to* $B$ for *total functions* from $A$ to $B$, i.e., functions whose domain is all of $A$.

Answer (score 1):

There are so many concepts in mathematics, and not all has a unique name that means exactly the same thing in every context.

Most probably in that specific book it is well explained what is meant by '*function*' (**within the book**!) However, if the domain of a function is 'not full', it is usually called *partial function*. Considering partial functions as 'primary' notions indeed can have some advantages which are probably used in the book.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible that the book uses some non-standrad convention or definition. The standard approach to functions is that a function must associate one, and only one, value to *every* element of the domain.

Comment: But it the problem with the example is that function is not defined for 3.

Comment: That's why Ittay wrote '*non-standard*'.